# Trigger CRON driven processor manually

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a bunch of flows, with the first processor in each triggered by CRON every day. Sometimes it's necessary to start the flow manually; for now, the only way to do is stop the processor, temporary replace CRON activation with timer one, start, stop, revert changes and start again. Is there any way, either programmatic or through REST, which allows us to skip these changes?

Comment: I face the same problem sometimes. I use a FlowFile Generator with CRON (every minute) to start the first processor or any in the pipeline and stop the FlowFile Generator after its done. It is a manual process though.

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate your **initial processor** that has a CRON defined, and connect it to the **same next** processor/PG.

Change **CRON to "Once-in-a-life-time" (10 years)**.

- Then, using **REST API** you can start and stop this processor without affecting your CRON schedule. Every time you start it - it will create FF.

  - To **avoid sending FlowFiles** on NIFI's restart - you can use: 
    `enable + start + stop + disable`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Then, using REST API you can start and stop this processor without affecting your CRON schedule." - do this differ in any way from starting/stopping from UI? It seems that CRON-driven processors don't generate FlowFiles on start from UI. When started from REST, they do?

Comment: when you start CRON driven processor, it will schedule next run based on CRON/Quartz expression. But will not produce FF immediately. Timer based schedule will produce FF on start and then after each period of time defined in expression you provide. This is true for both UI and REST invocation.
In your questions you are looking for solution to avoid changes and use rest API. I just thought this could work to solve your problem with automating the process using rest apis.